# Is it right to say "While I was back on my way home"

Tags: grammaticality, style

Is it right to say, "While I was back on my way home, ..."?

I think it is a bit awkward!

Comment: Something like "While I was on my way home" would work fine.

Comment: You wouldn't really say it that way, because you weren't "back on your way", you were "on your way back".

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty close but your word order is a bit off.

"While I was on my way back home," would work better. If the context is something like "While I was on my way back home, I saw two cats on a fence.

The more fluid way to say that would be "While I was on my way home, I saw two cats on a fence"